# Triangle rendering issue in directX

Tags: rendering, triangulation, directx-9

I am working with directX 9. I have a problem while rendering triangles using *drawprimitive*.
The problem is - When I am rendering the whole object made of several triangles, the triangle having all points on a single line shows gap in a whole closed object. I am showing the image below. The white dashed line is the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have try to order the all points in the object and then go to draw ,You can easily find the problem when draw like this.I think problem in precision varying.Try to check that..

Regards

Ratty

Comment: Yes, it was a precision problem. The third digit after decimal point was different. Thank You.